# WordPress i18n in Array throws Error

Tags: array, translation

i am wirting my very first plugin. For publishing it to the repository i want to make it translatable. On my options page i some arrays, which store the default settings. Somehow i get an error when implementing i18n.

```
class SettingsPagePrivacyHelper {

    private static $optionGroup = 'privacy_helper_option_group';
    private static $optionTitle = 'Simple Privacy Helper';

    /*
     * Default Setting for Options
     */
    private $commentsDefaults = array(
        'check'             => 1,
        'message'           => __('Ich habe die ###Privacy-Policy### zur Kenntnis genommen. Ich stimme zu, dass meine Angaben zur Kontaktaufnahme und für Rückfragen dauerhaft gespeichert werden.', 'privacy-helper'),
        'error'             => __('Sie müssen die Bedingungen akzeptieren.', 'privacy-helper'),
        'consent_check'     => 0,
    );

    private $regDefaults = array(
        'check'             => 1,
        'message'           => __('Ich habe die ###Privacy-Policy### zur Kenntnis genommen. Ich stimme zu, dass meine Angaben gespeichert werden.', 'privacy-helper'),
        'error'             => __('Sie müssen die Bedingungen akzeptieren.', 'privacy-helper')
    );

    private $wcDefaults = array(
        'check'             => 1,
        'message'           => __('Ich habe die ###Privacy-Policy### zur Kenntnis genommen. Ich stimme zu, dass meine Angaben zur Verarbeitung des Kaufes und auf Grund der Nachweispflicht gespeichert werden.', 'privacy-helper'),
        'error'             => __('Sie müssen die Bedingungen akzeptieren.', 'privacy-helper'),
        'reg-check'             => 1,
        'reg-message'           => __('Ich habe die ###Privacy-Policy### zur Kenntnis genommen. Ich stimme zu, dass meine Angaben zur Verarbeitung des Kaufes und auf Grund der Nachweispflicht gespeichert werden.', 'privacy-helper'),
        'reg-error'             => __('Sie müssen die Bedingungen akzeptieren.', 'privacy-helper')
    );

    private $cf7Defaults = array(
        'check'             => 1,
        'message'           => __('Ich habe die ###Privacy-Policy### zur Kenntnis genommen. Ich stimme zu, dass meine Angaben zur Kontaktaufnahme und für Rückfragen dauerhaft gespeichert werden.', 'privacy-helper'),
    );

    private $ytDefaults = array(
        'check'             => 1,
    );
}
```

WordPress gives me the following error: 
Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in [...]/settings-page.php on line 11

Does someone has an idea how to fix this?

Comment: you have a problem with your php syntax, probably mismatched quotes or perns

Comment: FYI if you want to publish your plugin on WordPress.org, your base language has to be English.

Comment: @swissspidy as far as i know the initial string language does not matter. There are many plugins in e.g. only dutch. I am planning to translate the plugin, thats why i asked my question. You can create a .po file when your plugin is accepted, thats what i am aiming for.

Comment: If I want to translate your plugin and don’t know German, I’m lost. Also, why create PO files when you can use translate.wordpress.org?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a PHP issue, not specific to WordPress.

PHP does not allow you to declare a property as an expression. It should be a literal. So you can not call a function inside a property declararion. (see Invalid property declarations in http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

The solution is to create a getter method and use it instead. Or else you could set the propery in the __construct() method.

So, for example, doing it on construct:

```
class MyClass {

    private $myProperty;

    function __construct() {
        $this->myProperty = [
            'foo' => __('bar')
        ];
    }

}
```

Or doing this as a getter:

```
class MyClass {


    private function getMyProperty() {

        return [
            'foo' => __('bar')
        ];


    }

}
```

Comment: Semicolons inside arrays there. I tried to edit, but says I need to change 6 characters minimum :-/